# cahcing flash recorded audio in a bytearray on client

Tags: flash, microphone, avaudiorecorder

I am building a small flash application to record audio from the client's computer. I wish to be able to use the microphone, store the recorded information in a byte array and then send it onwards. I saw the following piece of code that works fine with the camera:

> ```
>         var _loc_1:BitmapData;
>         var _loc_2:ByteArray;
>         _loc_1 = new BitmapData(video.width, video.height, false, 13421772);
>         _loc_1.draw(video, new Matrix());
>
>         _loc_2 = PNGEncoder.encode(_loc_1);
>         return Base64.encodeByteArray(_loc_2);
> ```

In order for this to work with audio I need classes like BitmapData and PNGEncoder that will work with audio and not just images \ video. Do you know of any such classes? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible by using flash alone.
You will have to stream the input to a server which then sends the data back.
Here's two very short threads discussing it:

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=88653

http://www.gotoandlearnforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=21974&p=115759

Also, about your code-example, I just want to say that unless you know what you're doing and need to store the data as a string, there's no need of encoding it with Base64, it'll waste both cpu-recourses and space.

Comment: I know that it's possible to cache a byte of arrays based on the image displayed on screen, thereby creating a local cache based on the images captured by the web camera. Are you sure something similar cannot be done with audio ?

Comment: You can access the graphical-output and do anything with that yes, but there's no way of accessing the audio-output in flash, and unfortunately you don't have that kind of control of the microphone either.
I was hoping this would have changed with the release of AS3 but it didn't.